# Call function with angular when scrolling

Tags: html, angularjs, scroll

Is there a way to detect, if a element was scrolled and call a function and do some stuff with angularJS? Something like a `ng-scroll` or so, which works simply like a `ng-click`? I didn't really find a solution...

This is what I would like to do:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.checkIfScrolling = function() {
    console.log("scrolled...");
  }
});
```

```css
.box-scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div app="myApp" controller="myController" class="box-scroll" ng-scroll="checkIfScrolling()">
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
  <div class="box-item">I'm an item within box-scroll</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing native, you'd have to wire up your own directive using the onscroll event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved without any directive also

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  //action to be performed
});
```

Comment: What's the best way to put this in a controller of a ng component?

Comment: Create a directive as ng-scroll and then u can add this functionality inside the link: of the diretive.